# Problem with fidelity value range obtained from this python code

Tags: programming, fidelity

I'm calculating for instance the fidelity between two pure two qubit state, using the following python code:

```
#calculate fidelity
from scipy.linalg import fractional_matrix_power


def fidelity(rho_pred , rho_trg):

  fid = np.trace( fractional_matrix_power((np.matmul((np.matmul(fractional_matrix_power(rho_pred, 0.5), rho_trg)) , fractional_matrix_power(rho_pred, 0.5)))), 0.5)


  return fid
```

what I'm getting is bigger than 1 (like 6), is something wrong with the code? Also fidelity includes imaginary part!?

Example Density Mtarix:

```
A = np.matrix([[ 0.02759643+0.j        , -1.24001054+0.31321969j,
         -0.65215435+0.64845159j,  0.27468692-0.06695888j],
        [-1.24001054-0.31321969j,  0.14355992+0.j        ,
          2.26107285+3.80321405j, -0.71228114-0.36857898j],
        [-0.65215435-0.64845159j,  2.26107285-3.80321405j,
          0.71370039+0.j        , -2.5757435 +0.08429232j],
        [ 0.27468692+0.06695888j, -0.71228114+0.36857898j,
         -2.5757435 -0.08429232j,  0.11514326+0.j        ]])
```

```
B = np.matrix([[ 0.02759643+0.j        ,  0.04772431+0.04103817j,
         -0.03512276+0.13587484j,  0.01716793-0.05369176j],
        [ 0.04772431-0.04103817j,  0.14355992+0.j        ,
          0.14131705+0.2872077j , -0.05015446-0.1183828j ],
        [-0.03512276-0.13587484j,  0.14131705-0.2872077j ,
          0.71370039+0.j        , -0.28620893-0.01619367j],
        [ 0.01716793+0.05369176j, -0.05015446+0.1183828j ,
         -0.28620893+0.01619367j,  0.11514326+0.j        ]])
```

Comment: for starters, I suspect np.sqrt() calculates the element-wise square root of a matrix, not the maxtrix to the power half. I also think * is element-wise multiplication where @ is matrix multiplication.

Comment: @DaftWullie I have changed the code  but still fidelity has the same problem, do you see any error?

Comment: @Farhad you still have one np.sqrt right after the np.trace.

Comment: @Guangliang also by changing it to fractional power, still same problem

Comment: Can you show us some of the examples you've tried, the answers they give, and the answers you expect them to give?

Comment: @DaftWullie my problem is, should not fidelity according to the definition always be  between 0 and 1 ? so if the coding is okay for any valid density matrix, value must be in range

Comment: @DaftWullie I'm sampling pure states according to Haar measure https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_haar_measure.html

Comment: OK, but if you're having trouble with your code, the first step of debugging is to make your problem reproducible. Don't go for the full complexity of sampling over some random measure. Test your code on specific examples (that you can also work out by hand!) and figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: What are the inputs to the function? Can you show example with nimbers in the matrices?

Comment: @RonCohen I have added example density matrixs

Comment: $A$ is not a density matrix. Just calculate its eigenvalues: they should all be between 0 and 1!